# SVG mask not working in IE9

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-9

Can someone tell me what's wrong with [this SVG](http://jsfiddle.net/6AL6B/)?
IE9 don't apply mask at all.

I found some svg mask examples that WORK in IE9, but didn't found any differences from my code.

I'm using a mask with radial gradient. But even with simple plain colors, it doesn't work.

```
<mask id="mask">
    <rect fill="white" x="15" y="0" width="10" height="200" stroke-width="0"/>
    <rect fill="url(#radialGradient)" x="15" y="10" width="10" height="180" stroke-width="0"/>
</mask>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran you code on jsFiddle. The problem is while you are drawing the line, x1 equals to x2. I have changed line's x2 to 21, and it worked.

Comment: Thank you very much! Maybe not the perfect solution, but worked as expected.